# SubSonic3 Update Question

Tags: subsonic3

Is it possible to do something like this in SubSonic3?

```
_db.Update<Product>()
    .Set("UnitPrice")
    .EqualTo(UnitPrice + 5)
    .Where<Product>(x=>x.ProductID==5)
    .Execute();
```

I would need something lik this:

```
UPDATE      Blocks
SET         OrderId = OrderId - 1
WHERE       ComponentId = 3
```

But in SubSonic3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can here is a sample for demonstrating how you can use subsonic 3

//  One thing you might not have seen with Linq To Sql is the ability to run Updates 
//and Inserts, which I've always missed and have now implemented with SubSonic 3.0:

```
            db.Update<Products>().Set(
                x => x.Discontinued == false, 
                x => x.ReorderLevel == 100)
               .Where(x=>x.Category==5)
               .Execute();

        db.Insert.Into<Region>(x => x.RegionID, x => x.RegionDescription)
          .Values(6, "Hawaii")
          .Execute();
```

and here a [link](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/subsonic-3-0-preview-2/) to the full demonstration

Comment: TiTaN, this isn't really doing what I want. I want to set a value that is equal to the current value -1 for instance. In your example, you're just setting all records to false and 100...

Comment: _db.Update<Product>()
    .Set(
    x => x.UnitPrice == x.UnitPrice + 5)
    .Where<Product>(x=>x.ProductID==5)
    .Execute();

Answer (score 0):

i do it as a select

```
var model = ClassName.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);

model.name = "new name";
model.tel = " new telephone;

model.save();
```

done